# How to change the default maximum number of epochs (200) of self-organizing map training in MATLAB2014R

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, som

I have a large set of data (100,000 observations) and have been using Matlab2014R.
I used the command:

net = selforgmap([dimension1 dimension2]);

But it seems that there is no options for me to change the default max epochs (200), which I suspect may not be sufficient, but I could not find anywhere to raise this number, including its own manual. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/cluster-with-self-organizing-map-neural-network.html) you can set the number of epochs as follows (their example):

Let's say you create a network like so:

```
net = selforgmap([2,3]);
```

Then in the Training phase of your network, you can set the # of epochs using dot notation as follows:

```
net.trainParam.epochs = Some number;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So @YingyuFeng does that answer your question?